# Is life a logical consequence of matter reacting to other matter within an endless reoccuring of ‘life-friendly’ natural conditions?

Tags: philosophy-of-biology

In other words, is life bound to originate in any environment that provides the life-supporting conditions over a longer period? Like temperatures, the tides (thus a tide regulating moon), a solid crust of the planet, the right amount of minerals and water, and so on.

Alternatively the question could be; what if there was no life on earth now and conditions would not change that much, would life logically evolve again on our planet? And if so, what is the chance of finding life on other planets?

Comment: Would recommend changing logical to necessary and logically to necessarily to fix the confusion of terms Mario is talking about. The science folks have numbers of probability for these questions, but the true underlying question here —for philosophy anyway— might be “given the circumstances where something is probable, will it necessarily occur given enough time?” The only true answer being: it is probable, but still not necessary. There was a great question about the gamblers delusion on this site that relates I think.

Comment: It may be fruitful to explore your question in terms of statistical chance and requisite time periods. See what Biology, Physics and (especially) Math has to say.

Answer (score 1):

*Life* is **not** a [logical consequence](https://www.iep.utm.edu/logcon/) of anything.

*Logical consequence* is a relation that holds between *sentences* and life is a "fact" and not a sentence.

Comment: Thank you. I am not a native speaker and not that familiar with the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively the question could be; what if there was no life on earth now and conditions would not change that much, would life logically evolve again on our planet?

No, not if *all* life was extinguished with condition otherwise unchanged. The current atmosphere is highly oxidative and this would be extremely hostile to the reformation of precursor molecules.

Prebiotic conditions had a reductive atmosphere.  Atomspheric free oxygen was only produced later, as a highly toxic biproduct of photosynthesis.  The catastrophic build up of the oxygenising atmosphere in fact heralded one of the earliest mass extinction events.

You should revise your concept of "life-supporting conditions".